# Is it appropriate to use a reference type in a From impl, like From<&Foo>

Tags: rust

I have two types, call them `Reusable` and `SingleUse`, such that it is possible to construct a `SingleUse` from a `Reusable`. I'd like to enforce the invariant that the former can be reused while the latter is consumed by accepting a `&Reusable` or a `SingleUse` parameter. Something like:

```rust
let re = Reusable{};
let su = SingleUse{source:re};
do_something(&re);
do_something(&re);
do_something(su);
```

I can accomplish this by defining a `From<&Reusable> for SingleUse` and then taking a `Into<SingleUse>` for the `do_something()` parameter, but I'm not certain whether or not this is a misuse of `From`/`Into`. Most examples I've seen involving `From` don't mention using references. [This article](https://ricardomartins.cc/2016/08/03/convenient_and_idiomatic_conversions_in_rust) has an example of a `From<&'a [T]>` but still suggests that `From`/`Into` are intended to operate on values (and contrasts that with other traits like `AsRef` intended to operate on references).

So I'm hoping to sanity-check that using `From` on a reference type is appropriate, or if not if there's a more idiomatic way to model this `Reusable`/`SingleUse` relationship?

---

Full example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1ada7adefea435cf50316c75979ad88)):

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Reusable { }

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SingleUse {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    source: Reusable,
}

impl From<&Reusable> for SingleUse {
    fn from(source: &Reusable) -> Self {
        SingleUse{source: source.clone()}
    }
}

fn do_something(input: impl Into<SingleUse>) {
    println!("Saw:{:?}", input.into());
}

fn main() {
    let re = Reusable{};
    let su = SingleUse{source: re.clone()};
    do_something(&re);
    do_something(&re);
    do_something(su);
}
```

Comment: Yes, [I've provided practical examples in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76338657/), though more in the sense of providing a view using references to internal fields of an opaque type that the view is needed of.

Answer (score 0):

std implements `From<&str> for {Box<str>,Rc<str>,String,Arc<str>,Vec<u8>}`, `From<&String> for String`, `From<&[T]> for {Box<[T]>,Rc<[T]>,Arc<[T]>,Vec<T>}` and some more. Especially note the `From<&String> for String` (essentially `Clone`) that is pretty similar to your situation. So I'd say this is fine.